# Matplotlib showing X axis labels out of order but based on their values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to have my graph show the x labels in the order of the below. But its putting them in the graph based on their values.

Can someone advise how to force the plot to show them in the below order?

1. How I want the X-axis to be ordered:

```
'TD1BALMO','TD1CURMON','TD1+1_M', 'TD1+2_M', 'TD1+3_M', 'TD1+4_M', 'TD1+5_M'
```

2. how it is being ordered (I don't know why)

```
'TD1+1_M', 'TD1+2_M', 'TD1+3_M', 'TD1+4_M', 'TD1+5_M', 'TD1BALMO','TD1CURMON'
```

Assign routes for 3.30.2020 to a variable:

```
TD3_FFA_Months = FFA_dirty_rates[FFA_dirty_rates.RouteIdentifier.isin(['TD1BALMO','TD1CURMON','TD1+1_M', 'TD1+2_M', 'TD1+3_M', 'TD1+4_M', 'TD1+5_M']) & (FFA_dirty_rates.ArchiveDate == '2020-03-30')]
```

Visualizing the data

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
plt.plot('RouteIdentifier', 'RouteAverage', data=TD3_FFA_Months, marker='o', markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=12, color='skyblue', linewidth=4)
plt.xlabel('Forward Months')
plt.ylabel('WS Rates')
plt.title('Rates over months and years')
plt.show()
```

I am having trouble putting in a picture but the chart is showing the X axis in the below order. Notice the TD1BALMO and TD1CURMO were placed at the end of the x axis.

```
'TD1+1_M', 'TD1+2_M', 'TD1+3_M', 'TD1+4_M', 'TD1+5_M', 'TD1BALMO','TD1CURMON'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyplot x-axis being sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31117984/pyplot-x-axis-being-sorted)

Comment: I read the post you linked to but I'm still confused. Do I need to use xticks?

Comment: I guess what you are trying to do is order the xticks, isn't it?

Comment: I think so. I'm just trying to customize the order of the x axis labels. I need to have 'TD1BALMO' and 'TD!CURMON' as the first 2 in the chart and they are currently showing up as the last 2. Do you know how to switch them?